# Can I use old code by myself to build on for my entry in the Ubuntu App Showdown contest?

Tags: application-development

Or does it have to be started completely from scratch at 18th of June?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can start your app already, but you should wait with submitting it at least until the 18th June when the contest starts.

You can reuse old code bits, but you shouldn't just submit an application you already created in the past. It must have been created from scratch for the contest.

Comment: By submitting you mean actually publishing to the Software Center? So should we submit like a preliminary version on the 18th?

Comment: @JaspervandenBosch You might want to ask this as a separate question, as it seems as much about *what* (or *what quality*) to submit rather than *how* or *from what sources* to produce it or *when* to submit it.

Comment: Actually I guess my question is answered by http://askubuntu.com/questions/151148/how-do-i-participate-in-the-ubuntu-app-showdown

Comment: Does a conversion from Manual window building to quickly count as 're-coding it'? e.g. https://launchpad.net/~aking1012-com/+archive/lenstoggle

Comment: Sorry, that wouldn't count as an application from scratch. Porting an existing app to Quickly is a trivial task in which you end up with a full-blown app 90% of the code of which you wrote before the contest, thus giving you an unfair advantage over the other participants.