# Can I develop an "existing" application for the showdown?

Tags: application-development

I want to develop an app for the new Ubuntu's contest, but I have two questions:

1. Can I develop an "existing" app, which I added to Launchpad some days ago, but which no source code was uploaded?
2. Can I use external programs, such QEMU or Wget to develop them? For example, calling them with things like `os.system()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding your first question, you are supposed to develop an app from scratch. But, I am sure the judges won't mind if you use some of the ideas and code from your existing app given that you were the one who created the other app as well.

- [Can I use old code by myself to build on for my entry in the Ubuntu App Showdown contest?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151196/can-i-use-old-code-by-myself-to-build-on-for-my-entry-in-the-ubuntu-app-showdown)

And for the second question, you can use anything as long as they exist in the Ubuntu 12.04 repositories. This restriction is because of the App Review Board guidelines.

Relevant parts from the [guidelines](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppReviewBoard/Review/Guidelines#Code) below:

> - You can include any libraries that are part of your app. For example, if you're writing a Python game, and you've written a Python library to store character data, it's fine to include that with your app.
> - If your app depends on external libraries, please make sure that your app runs on the current versions shipped in Ubuntu. (We're open to considering dependencies on backported libraries, on a case-by-case basis, but only if the backport is a new library and not an updated version of an existing library.)
> - No other software can depend on the application being submitted (e.g. development libraries should be submitted to main/universe or upstream to Debian instead).
> - Applications must be able to be built with tools & libraries in the Ubuntu archive. Apps may bundle additional libraries they depend on, but may not include new versions of already packaged libraries.

Comment: OK, so then I'm able to develop my Virtuam application :)

Comment: https://launchpad.net/virtuam

Comment: But, just to be sure, I would suggest you wait for a more official answer.

Comment: The reason for the "from scratch" requirement was to put all contestants on equal footing.  If you had the idea, but hadn't started on the code, then it would be fair.  If you've been developing it for a couple weeks already, and just haven't uploaded the code yet, then it wouldn't be fair.

Answer (score 1):

So long as no code exists before the three-week period, you are good to go!