# Where to ask questions related to ubuntu app developer showdown?

Tags: application-development

i recently saw ubuntu app developer showdown and i am very excited about it.
i have some questions about it and i seriously want good answers can you tell me an official or unofficial communities forums or emails where i can get good anwsers thanks.

[Can I use old code by myself to build on for my entry in the Ubuntu App Showdown contest?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151196/can-i-use-old-code-by-myself-to-build-on-for-my-entry-in-the-ubuntu-app-showdown)

[How do I participate in the Ubuntu App Showdown?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151148/how-do-i-participate-in-the-ubuntu-app-showdown)

already seen these questions

Comment: Shouldnt this be a meta/

Comment: @Lord Of Time : If the question is can I ask ubuntuappshowdown qustion in in askubuntu ,it is to be moved to meta ,but this question is more general :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Feel free to ask

You can ask ubuntushowdown questions here ,because it is directly related to ubuntu, tag them with [application-development](/questions/tagged/application-development)

Comment: hey see my thread can you anwser my questions http://askubuntu.com/questions/151288/some-questions-related-to-ubuntu-app-showdown

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the site : http://developer.ubuntu.com

This site contains all the information that you will need plus an extra help with coding.

Comment: i know this site as you can see i have already seen most pages but still thanks :)