# some questions related to ubuntu app showdown

Tags: application-development

I have some questions about ubuntu appshowdown

My questions:

- Can i submit more than one app in the contest and tell me more about this suppose i submit 5 apps out of which one is won then will it be valid if 2 or 3 are won
- I think the number of t-shirts does not depends upon number of apps one per person
- For development i have to use quickly but can i use third party libraries for GUI or other work i think i will need it for eg. pyside
- The first and second winner will get laptop + mobile too right or not the mobile
- How the prizes will be delivered will they charge(i don't think so)
- I would like to use multiple libraries i can use htme right ?
  more details are always welcomes I have read mostly all ubuntu app showdown related pages but if you find something in background than tell me

Note:
i am not saying that i am going to win just questions don't take it in that way

Comment: One question per one question please :-)

Comment: you mean i should make new questions out of these questions :)

Answer (score 3):

Hi I think most questions can be answered here. 
http://developer.ubuntu.com/showdown/rules/ and http://developer.ubuntu.com/showdown/

I think should be submitted as different questions but I'll try to answer.

> For development i have to use quickly but can i use third party libraries for GUI or other work i think i will need it for eg. pyside

My understanding is that it has to be availble through ubuntu repo. Quickly makes this easy. pyside might be there.

> The first and second winner will get laptop + mobile too right or not the mobile

My understanding is that you get both if you get first or second prize.

Comment: what about multiple apps

Comment: according to latest news now it is no longer compulsory to use quickly so i will use qt with qt creator what is meant by /opt directory will qt creator satisfy that need by default